# Joomla inner pages showing 404 Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3.0

I have transfered my joomla 3.5.1 with Redshop installation from one domain to another domain like

from example.com to example.com/folder

I have transfered all the files and DB and changed the configuration file with the new db details.

Now the front page and administrator section is working fine, but when I am trying to access the inner pages also from the component sh404SEF the page is showing 404 not found.
Can any one has the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

I just change the line in .htaccess to RewriteBase /foldername and its work.